# What adjective descibes a 'stooge' in a Socratic dialogue?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose one constructs a dialogue in which a second participant is clearly there just to provide ballast while the first participant (the author) promotes a point of view. You could refer to the second as a stooge, a prop etc. But I'm looking for an adjective, and "the stoogy guy" doesn't sound all that learned. (-:

A better noun than 'stooge' might lead to a good adjective, but all I really need is the adjective.

Comment: If you Google the term "Socratic stooge", it comes up in a few books...so maybe it's not an official word, let alone a single word, but it exists nonetheless (only 277k results on Google, though, so the term is not _that_ common).

Comment: Perhaps _defending_? _Interlocutary_?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any *single* word representing the role you're describing... But depending whether the role of the "stooge" is adversarial or complementary, I do think an idiom might be appropriate:

**Straw man**: a weak or imaginary argument or opponent that is set up to be easily defeated ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/straw%20man))

OR

**Straight man**: a member of a comedy team who says things that allow a partner to make jokes ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/straight%20man))

---

Update: I can't provide the links, but "Socratic straw man" returned about 90k Google results while "Socratic straight man" returned about 60k.

Comment: Indeed the role is that of a straight man, AKA stooge or setup man. But I can't make that into an adjective any better than I can "stooge" itself.

Answer (score 0):

One could combine "stooge" with the suffix "-eous" (meaning resembling) to create "stoogeous," but this isn't likely to be understood (especially in writing) seeing as a quick Google search for "stoogeous" yielded no relevant results.  Other options include "stooge-like," "stoogen" (a slang term which would be used as an adjective), or "stooger" (which is also uncommon, but would be used as a noun).

I believe that all of these words' meanings could be guessed based on context, however, it's usually best to use words/phrases which could be easily looked up on the internet.